# can't set custom cell class's variable

Tags: swift, custom-cell

I created a table view and cell is custom style, I did hook up the cell with custom class and cell's id in `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: , for:)`function.

I added an image view in the cell, and add it as `IBOutlet` into custom cell class. In custom cell class, I created get and set variable called `tableImage` to change the image in the image view.

But in

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

I still can't set tableImage. The error shows Value of type `UITableViewCell` has no member `tableImage`.

Comment: Could you please post your code

Comment: It's hard to understand where is the problem, if you don't show the code, but it seems you forgot to specify the cell itself at the end of the row with "as! myCustomCellName"

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you add as! yourCustomTableViewCell after the dequeueReusableCell function?

```
yourTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCell", for: indexPath) as! yourCustomTableViewCell
```

Comment: wow, that's incredible... it works now just after I add it! Thanks so much!